# Why $d_xG_{|T_xX}=0\implies d_xG=\lambda_1d_xF_1+\cdots+\lambda_md_xF_m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand this proof of this theorem of a book I'm reading in basic algebraic geometry:

**Theorem**

Let $X$ be a closed affine subset and $x\in X$. The restriction of  $d_x$ to $I_X(x)$ defines a isomorphism of $k$-vectorial spaces between the quotient $I_X(x)/I_X(x)^2$ and the dual $(T_xX)^*$.

Thus, we get the isomorphism

$$T_xX\cong \big(I_X(x)/I_X(x)^2\big)^*.$$

**Proof**

Consider the restriction $d_x:I_X(x)\to (T_xX)^*$. We have to show that

$$im(d_x)=(T_xX)^* \ \text{and}\ \ker(d_x)=(I_X(x))^2$$

First, note that every linear form $\varphi$ in $T_xX$ is induced by a linear function $f$ in $\mathbb A^N$ with $d_xf=\varphi$ and $f(x)=0$ and then $im(d_x)=(T_xX)^*$. Now, we will show that $\ker(d_x)=I_X(x)^2$. We have already seen that $I_X(x)\subset \ker(d_x)$. Let's prove the converse.

Without loss of generality, suppose $x=(0,\ldots,0)$. take $g\in I_X(x)$ such that $d_xg=0$ and suppose $g$ is induced by a polynomial $G\in k[T_1,\ldots, T_N]$. Thus, $d_xG=0$ in $T_xX$. So, $d_xG$ is the combination of the equations of $T_xX$, i. e., If $I(X)=(F_1,\ldots,F_m)$, then

$$d_xG=\lambda_1d_xF_1+\cdots+\lambda_md_xF_m$$

and the proof continues...

My question is quite simple, I didn't understand why $d_xG_{|T_xX}=0\implies d_xG=\lambda_1d_xF_1+\cdots+\lambda_md_xF_m$

I really need help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is linear algebra. Let $T_1,\ldots,T_m:V\to k$ be linear transformations in the dual of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $k$ and take $K=\bigcap_i\ker T_i$. If $G\in V^*$ such that $G|_K=0$, then $G=\lambda_1T_1+\cdots+\lambda_mT_m$ for certain $\lambda_i\in K$.

Proof: We may assume without loss of generality that the $T_i$ are linearly independent as elements of the dual vector space, and so we may assume that they are the first $m$ coordinate functions for some fixed basis of $V$ (the first $m$ elements of the dual basis). Therefore it is easy to see that $K\simeq\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n):a_1=\cdots=a_m=0\}\leq k^n$. The fact that $G$ vanishes on $K$ means that $G$ can be written as a linear combination of the first $m$ coordinate functions. $\Box$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I didn't know that this is a fact of linear algebra.

Comment: Dear Robert to prove the isomorphism $K\cong \{a_1,\ldots, a_n):a_1=\ldots=a_m=0\}$ I defined this function  $\varphi: K\to (0,\ldots,0,a_{m+1},\ldots,a_n)$, $a\mapsto (T_1(a),\ldots,T_n(a))$, am I right?

Comment: Let $T_1,\ldots,T_m,S_{m+1},\ldots,S_n$ be a basis for the dual space. The function should be $V\to k^n$ where $a\mapsto (T_1(a),\ldots,T_m(a),S_{m+1}(a),\ldots,S_n(a))$.